# Windows Phone 7 update a textblock permanently

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stopwatch

I am trying to program some kind of stopwatch for Windows Phone 7. To measure the elapsed time I use the Stopwatch class. To print the output I use a textblock. But I would like the textblock to show the elapsed time all the time .

Unitl now I can only update the textblock on events (I use a button_Click event)
I tried a while(true) loop but this only freezes the phone.

Has anyone a good idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StopWatch` class doesn't have any events, so if you want to bind, you have to either write your own class or poll the StopWatch with a timer.
You can use Binding to bind properties from the TextBlock to a stopwatch. First add this DataContext binding to your page xaml.

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
```

Then bind your textblock like so

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding StopwatchTime}" />
```

and in the code behind, add DependancyProperty and the necessary timer code.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StopwatchTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StopwatchTime", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string StopwatchTime
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StopwatchTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StopwatchTimeProperty, value); }
    }
```

and the timer code somewhere...

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2); // customize update interval
        timer.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopwatchTime = sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString(); // customize format
        };
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer. I was looking for something like the Binding but did not find. unfrotunately it does not work (as I think it should)  I wanted to use a variable String show = randomTimespanvariable.ToString();

Comment: The reason binding doesn't work is very simple. Stopwatch.Elapsed is not a DependancyProperty. The reason it isn't is because you don't want to update its value every 1 milisecond. There's no elegant binding solution for your case. I tried the above code and it worked really nice even with `Timespan.FromSeconds(0.1)` as Interval.

Comment: If you still want binding, just assign the myStopWatch.Elapsed value into a DependancyPeoprty of type string, and then just bind your TextBlock to that, but functionally you are not changing anything, perhaps no need to invoke the Dispatcher. Let me know if you need code help with that.

Comment: ...I wanted to use a variable String show = randomTimespanvariable.ToString(); but the "TextBlock" keeps void :( I think I have some problem whit the scope of the Variable. When the Variable  show is defined in the MainPage do i have to  write : WindowsPhoneApplication1.MainPage.show do I have to write it like this?   <TextBlock Text="{Binding WindowsPhoneApplication1.MainPage.show}" /> Im sorry for the mess I did I always wanna press enter to make a newline and it sends the comment befor Im finished.

Comment: Yes I wuold be happy about some help. Did you think about something like this? `TimeSpan elapsedTime = stopWatch.Elapsed;
String textBoxText = elapsedTime.ToString();` and then Bind it like this? `<TextBlock Text="{Binding textBoxText}" />`